# jQuery delay on CSS change

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking to add a 300 millisecond delay to the function of this jQuery but not 100% sure where it should sit?

I understand that I need to add `.delay(300)` but wasn't too sure where it has to go in the code below.

```
$("#menu1-holder").mouseleave(function(){
    $('#menu1-holder').css('display', 'none');
});
```

OR... should I be using `setTimeout`? If so where should that be placed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#menu1-holder").mouseleave(function(){
var that = $(this);
setTimeout(function(){
   that.css('display', 'none');
}, 300);    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do like this with simple script:

```
$("#menu1-holder").mouseleave(function(){
    $('#menu1-holder').delay(300).css('display', 'none');
});
```

Check this http://api.jquery.com/delay/